# Defining independent formatting context

Tags: html, css

Reading this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model), I was struggling to define independent formatting context.

Is independent formatting context when: element creates different formatting context for its children than the one its parents made for it OR a formatting context anything other than `flow` i.e. Block-formatting context, Flex formatting context, Grid-formatting context etc?

Comment: read this: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#independent-formatting-context maybe better than the MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you reference is describing the engineering behind how a browser should render a web page - the underlying design theory. It is not describing how the programmer should format a web page. The distinction is important. In your question, it is apparent that you understand this - but we need to establish this as a starting point *(especially for future readers).*

Given that the browser turns code into a visual experience, the most fundamental concept for how the browser does that is: everything is either a box or inside a box, or both (the famous [*CSS Box Model*](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)). Thus, boxes are formatted according to certain rules - especially as they relate to one another. Boxes inside boxes inherit certain types of styling from their parent boxes, and pass the styles on to their child boxes.

In some cases, though, there must be exceptions to some rules so that certain formatting changes will only affect a specific part of the page.

Basically, the Independent Formatting Context (IFC) is related to this matter of CSS inheritance.

When an IFC is created, the CSS that is normally inherited from parent elements works differently than normal. Similarly, styling that would normally affect the rest of the document is contained to a specific container (box) or element.

IFCs allow the browser to contain (as in "won't leak out") certain undesirable or tricky formatting - such as when floats (e.g. `float:left`) [collapse the container](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#the-great-collapse) they are in. By changing the formatting context, the collapsed height can be contained to one specific element and the container height restored.

Similarly, the usual formatting inheritance rules are suspended for CSS Grid containers.

That's really all that this concept is describing.

So the answer to your question is more of the first than of the second, although the contexts you mention are all IFCs.

Why do you need to know about this? The changes and exceptions. Read this:

[MDN - Anonymous Boxes and Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model#Anonymous_boxes)

And these bits about the not-so-new-anymore "box-sizing" property:

https://pressupinc.com/blog/2014/01/whats-wrong-css-box-model-fix/

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing

### References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model

https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#box-model-history